# Import list to excel

Tags: list-manipulation, export, excel

If I have several lists such as:

```
alllists={{{30.,0.538342}, {30.1667, 0.53829}, {30.3333, 0.537987}......{{30., 0.527173}, {30.1667, 0.527403}, {30.3333, 0.527863}, {30.5,0.528402}, {30.6666, 0.528819}, {30.8333, 0.529406}, {30.9999, 
  0.530284}, {{}......................}}}
```

How can I import the lists to excel?. Specifically, how can I import the first list to the first two columns (the x and y parts of the list in different columns), the second to the following columns and so on?

Comment: `Export["file.xlsx",alllists]` should work.  What's the problem?

Comment: @bobthechemist thanks but the problem is that it exports the list into different "sheets" is there any way to export it into the same excel sheet in different columns?

Comment: Probably. You should provide a MWE to work with.

Comment: See [XLSX](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/XLSX.html). From the point of view transferring the data from within *Mathematica*, the operation is `Export`.  `Import` would transfer data from Excel into *Mathematica*.  So you'd probably be interested in the information about exporting to Excel in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate some fake data.  I'm assuming this is what your list looks like.

```
data = Range[100];
datap = Partition[ Partition[data, 2], 10];
```

Each list is of the same length, so exporting can be done with `Export["filename.xlsx",MapThread[Join@##&, datap]`.  If, however, your lists are *not* all the same length:

```
datap1 = With[{d = Partition[data, 2]}, {d[[1 ;; 5]], d[[6 ;; 15]], 
   d[[16 ;; 30]], d[[31 ;; 50]]}]
```

Then they need to be padded first:

```
Export["filename.xlsx", 
 MapThread[Join@## &, 
  PadRight[#, Max[Length /@ datap1], {{Null, Null}}] & /@ datap1]]
```